# what's the best way to consume an axis 1.3 web service using visual studio 2005 in c++

Tags: visual-c++, unmanaged, axis

I'm trying to consume an axis web service in VS 2005 & unmanaged c++..

The inbuilt sproxy.exe in VS falls over with a namespace error as the input/output namespaces are different.. though if I consume the web service in c# it works fine..

i've investigated gSOAP as well as Axis C++ both seem rather complex for what I need

All these tools could potentially do the job (with the exception of sproxy as i'd have to do a lot of work to get this working I think).. does anyone have any links or information on the best way to go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

gSoap is **the** SOAP implementation in C++. Also, since server side is Axis, you can expect least problems using axis in c++ side too.

Any other choice is going away from proven path, the solution might be better for you, but you'll not find much help along the way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) - I've actually decided to go the Axis route as gSoap's licensing doesnt fit what we are looking at.. 

Now we have other problems :) using Axis2c and the wsdl2c tool, I keep on getting a reference to axis2_char.h - which cant be found.. any thoughts?

Thanks